# Get error after content database restore to another server

Tags: sql-server, backup, content-database, restore

I have some problem with restore sharepoint content database.

1. get back up content data base from server A.
2. then restore to SQL server server B.
3. create a new web application in server B.
4. add restored database to new web application.
5. I go to "view all connection" section show all sites

it seems very things is OK! but when I click site URL, show me this error:

> This page can’t be displayed
>
> Make sure the web address http://sscg:200 is correct.
>    Look for the page with your search engine. 
>    Refresh the page in a few minutes.

anybody has idea to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem, after restore content database and create web application, Mount restore content database to new web application.

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase "MyDatabase" -DatabaseServer "MyServer" -WebApplication http://sitename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to detach the content database and attach it again using powershell...

also do you have the root level site collection in new webapplication...

check from central admin..."/" should be 1st in your site collection list....normally root level missing.